# How to read an SPSS file for multiple select questions?

Tags: r, spss

I am reading an SPSS file for importing a dataframe. Everything is working fine but I am not getting the multiple select response questions with labels. When I try to select multiple select option from the dropdown, it shows the data incorrect. I have used

```
Banner1 = w %>% 
tab_cells(mrset(as.category(temp1))) %>%
tab_cols(total(),mrset(as.category(temp2))) %>% 
tab_stat_cases(total_row_position = "none",label = "")
tab_pivot(Banner1)


Banner2 = w %>%
  tab_cells(mrset(as.category(temp1))) %>%
  tab_cols(total(),mrset(as.category(temp2))) %>% 
  tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = "below",label = "")%>%
tab_last_sig_cpct(sig_labels = paste0("<span style='color:red'>",LETTERS, "</b>"))
tab_pivot(Banner2)
```

Where temp1 and temp2 are arguments passed into R script from PHP.

Can anyone help me with the syntax how to use MRSET for multiple select options?
 [image: Here's the image of the dataframe]

Comment: What do your data look like?  How are you importing the SPSS file (foreign package, haven package, some other way)?  If you simply View() your data, do the labels appear?

Comment: @KevinTroy I am importing the data using the expss and foreign package. The imported data set is taking the question number and the data imported is all 0. Incorrect data to be precise.

Comment: @KevinTroyI have added an image of the data frame above. Just for clarification on how the data frame looks like for multiple sets of questions.